# UX, IXD audio podcasts to follow

Tags: resources

What audio podcasts would you recommend on usabilty, information architecture, iteraction design?

I listen to these:

- [Boxes and arrows podcasts](http://castroller.com/podcasts/BoxesAndArrows)
- [UIE podcasts](http://www.uie.com/brainsparks/audio/)
- [Adaptive Path](http://feeds.feedburner.com/AdaptivePathPodcast)

Answer (score 7):

I'd also recommend the dConstruct conference podcasts (the last few years are all available) - they also include some interesting talks on social media, as well as usability and UX topics:

2009: http://2009.dconstruct.org/podcast/

Also: http://2008.dconstruct.org/podcast/(2008), http://2007.dconstruct.org/podcast/(2007)

Comment: Oh, those are really great, I've listened to some. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend the [Pixel8 Podcast](http://community.infragistics.com/pixel8/default.aspx).

> Pixel8 is an audio and video podcast
>   series bringing UX and technology
>   experts together to discuss user
>   experience in the .NET space.

Answer (score 4):

Gerry Gaffney's [UXPod](http://www.infodesign.com.au/uxpod) is also worth a look

Cheers
R

.............................

Video: If you have iTunes you may want to check out the [Stanford HCI](http://deimos3.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/Browse/itunes.stanford.edu.1357108180) seminars

Answer (score 2):

37signals people have just started their podcast:

http://37signals.com/podcast

Also a list here:
http://designm.ag/resources/design-podcasts/